# How can I buy from Software Center from my Mac computer?

Tags: software-center, mac, macosx

I want to purchase software for my Ubuntu 12.04 (through Sofware Center) but now I can't use my Ubuntu computer (it's not at home), I'm only with my Mac, and the software I want to buy has a reduced price just until November 3... How can I buy from Ubuntu Software Center from my Mac? I have an account already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can buy using another computer
- You can use a live disk to boot your mac into Ubuntu
- If your really lucky the distributor will have "keys" that work in software center

Your purchase is linked to your account, so really you just need to log in "somewhere" and make the purchase.

I recommend using a Live CD or USB stick to do what you want.

You could also boot using parallels or similar.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/ is as close as I can find to an online store and it doesn't appear to allow purchases.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/tos/ - says you can re-download forever.

Comment: I've used another Ubuntu Linux computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to do this is to [install Ubuntu on a virtual machine](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/install-run-ubuntu-linux-virtualbox/) within OSX and download the software on that.  As long as you log in with the same credentials on both instances of Ubuntu, your purchase will be remembered.